# Input method menu item is not displayed on system menu of swing app on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java

On my Ubuntu box, I installed the City input method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/imf/spi-tutorial.html) by copying the CityIM.jar file to jre/lib/ext of my jdk. Then launch a swing application (for exampe freeMind), putting focus on a text field, opening the system menu of the application, but I don't see any "Select Input Method" menu item on that menu as said in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/imf/spi-sample/CityIM.html

Do you have any idea why I can see that menu item? Thanks.

Environment info:

- Ubuntu desktop
- Jdk 1.6.0_21 "standalone" e.g. the bundle downloaded    directly from
  Oracle site, not the jdk install via ubuntu apt-get

Comment: I tried it on Windows and Debian. On Windows it went smoothly. On Debian with Oracle Java 1.6.024 it doesn't work. I placed the jar in a directory taken from `System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs")`. Window manager: OpenBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *feature* of some java environments, that the system menu does not include the *Select Input Method* item. For example Linux, Solaris, applets inside a browser. There is an article about it at javadesktop.org: 
[Input Method Selection by a Hot Key](http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/InputMethod/index.html#Input_method_selection_by_a_hot_key).

For all platforms there is a possibility to have a hotkey triggering input method selection menu, so for Ubuntu this is the only way of setting it. In the article mentioned they offer `InputMethodHotKey.jar`, which is a nice gui for configuring this hotkey. I verified, it works on Debian.